# how to detect exit code of an executable inside ssis

Tags: ssis

[How to fail an SSIS Job from an EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317714/how-to-fail-an-ssis-job-from-an-exe-file) asks "how can i detect the failure".

I'm interested in knowing what the return code was, not just if it was <> 0.

At the moment i think i will have to have the executable write to standardErr, and parse that to detect outcomes which is achievable because the output can be redirected to a chosen StandardErrorVariable.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - I think that is your best option. Presumably you'll be using a try...catch idea. You could return try catch errors as less than 0; positive numbers for any positive outcomes you have.